# Databricks Job Queries

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a Scala code in Databricks and I have created a Job and mapped this code and executed though Databricks job.

If there is a failure in the code in the databricks notebook in a particular block, the corresponding notebook blocks returns as 'Command Skipped' but overall the Job says 'Successful'

My question is how to capture those notebook block failure and set Job as Failure.

Comment: Find below explanation [link]( https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)  **exit(value: String): void Exit a notebook with a value. If you call a notebook using the run method, this is the value returned.

Copy to clipboardCopy
dbutils.notebook.exit("returnValue")
Calling dbutils.notebook.exit in a job causes the notebook to complete successfully. If you want to cause the job to fail, throw an exception.**

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I am running my notebook using the same process with run method. The problem is, my notebook has 5 blocks and if the 2nd block failed then the block 3,4,5 fails with an error 'command skipped' and the overall run shows Success from Databricks. Even If I put an exception, the databricks job result will show success.

Comment: Sathya, you can raise the error like this. `if(condition){ print("Something") else:
      raise ValueError('Data Match Unsuccessful))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should create a handling exceptions mechanism in order to forcefully understand what is going on behind the scenes.

```
try{ func() or dbutils.notebook.run() } catch {case ex: Exception => println("Exception caught in main: " + ex);}
```

Additionally, you can force your notebook to be triggered by another notebook by executing the `dbutils.notebook.run(./insert_your_notebook_path_here)`. This probably will give you back an error message.